# azure applcation gateway to secure protocol

Tags: azure-application-gateway

I have configured azure load balancer which points my public Ip http, and I reach my website and working fine.

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVB7w.png)]

Now, I want to achieve a routing rule is used to redirect the application traffic from HTTP protocol to HTTPS secure protocol with the help of azure application gateway.

Can we simply add our HTTPS services to the health probe after installing an SSL certificate on the load balancer?  I don't have much knowledge in networking any help highly appreciate.

Comment: Are you asking about putting App Gateway behind the load balancer?  Load Balancer is a layer 4 service so it only cares about IP and Port, you can just point 443 directly to the App Gateway.  You'd configure the HTTP-to-HTTPS redirect rule on the App Gateway itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment it works fine successfully.***

you are able to configure your public Ip address to https using Azure application gateway. Try to create a self-signed certificate like below:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate `
  -certstorelocation cert:\localmachine\my `
  -dnsname www.contoso.com
```

[image]

```
#To create pfx file
   $pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "Azure"-Force -AsPlainText
   Export-PfxCertificate `
   -cert cert:\localMachine\my\<YOURTHUMBPRINT>  `
   -FilePath c:\appgwcert.pfx `
   -Password $pwd
```

[image]

Try to create an application gateway. you can use your exciting public Ip address like below.

[image]

In routing rule add your frontend Ip as ***public*** and protocol _ HTTPS _ as_ 443 ports _ and upload a ***pfx certificate*** like below:

[image]

Then, try to create listener with port 8080 with http and add routing rule as same and verify the backend status is healthy like below:

[image]

When I test the http protocol with Ip address redirect successfully like below:

[image]